# Cache "go get" in docker build

Tags: unit-testing, go, docker, docker-compose

I want to encapsulate my golang unit testing in a docker-compose script because it depends on several external services. My application has quite a lot of dependencies, so it takes a while to `go get`.

How can I cache packages in a way that allows the docker container to build without having to download all dependencies every time I want to test?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.7

CMD ["go", "test", "-v"]

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app

COPY . /go/src/app
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
```

Every time I want to run my unit tests I run `docker-compose up --build backend-test` on the following script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ...
  backend-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: backend-test
    depends_on:
      ...
```

But now `go-wrapper download` is called each time I want to run the tests and it takes a looong time to complete.

Solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to "cache" the dependencies, do it in a vendor directory so you know exactly what version you have cached. If you don't want to use `vendor/`, just copy in your GOPATH.

Comment: You might be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) as a way to run these kind of tasks. Compose is designed more for running services, where as dobi is focused on these type of build tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I use [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor). It keeps your dependencies in a vendor dir inside your project according to golang vendor conventions. This will still need to be copied to your docker image on build.

But there are very good reasons not to vendor. For example when you are building a pkg you should not vendor. When you have different pkg's using different versions of dependencies things get messy. This can be remedied by only vendoring executables.

So if you have a good reason not to vendor you can seperate a few steps.
Putting them in the right order will speed things up.

You can create a shell script (`get.sh`) with some `go get` commands for dependencies. (you can put these in your Dockerfile, but they have a line limit)

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
go get github.com/pborman/uuid
go get golang.org/x/net/context
go get golang.org/x/net/http2
go get golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack
```

Then in your Dockerfile you first copy and execute the shell script.
Each time you update the get.sh it will rebuild entirely. It still runs `got get ./...` to make sure all dependencies are there. But if everything is added in the `get.sh` script, you will get a decent speed boost.

```
FROM golang:1.6

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app

COPY get.sh /go/src/app

WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN bash get.sh

COPY . /go/src/app

RUN go get ./...

CMD go test -v
```

The general idea is that you keep frequently changing content lower in your Dockerfile and stuff that is pretty constant at the top. Even if you have to add another command or two. Docker will go line by line until it finds something that needs a rebuild and will then do every line after that too.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an answer to your question, but ironically found a question I have an answer to (how to run docker tests quickly).  If you really want fast tests, you should ideally avoid rebuilding the container at all when you run them.  But wait, how to get the new source code onto the container?  Volumes my friend, volumes.  Here's how I've set this up:

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
backend-test:
  volumes:
    - .:/path/to/myapp
```

Where /path/to/myapp is the path in the image, of course.  You'll have to explicitly pass in this image for dev:

```
docker-compose up -f docker-compose.dev.yml
```

But now, when you run your tests, you're not going to use docker-compose anymore, you're going to use docker exec:

```
docker exec -it backend-test go test
```

If you do this right, your src dir in the backend-test container will always be up to date because it's in fact a mounted volume.  Attaching to a running container and running tests should prove far faster than spinning up a new one each time.

EDIT: Commenter correctly pointed out that this only avoids rebuilding the image when you're dependencies haven't changed (no need `go get`).  The nice thing is that it not only avoids rebuilding, but it also avoids restarting.  When I'm testing like this, and I add a dependency, I typically just `go get` directly from my test console. It can be a bit tricky to get `go get` to work within your container, but one way is to forward your ssh agent through to your container by [mounting SSH_AUTH_SOCK](https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521).  Sadly, you can't mount volumes during build, so you may need to include some kind of deploy key in your image if you want your build target to be able to pull fresh dependencies before running tests.  However, The main point of my answer was to separate out the build and test, to avoid the full build until you're ready to generate the final artifact.

That said, I think I *might* understand that I'm not answering the question in the way that you asked it.  In ruby, the answer would be as simple as copying the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, and running `bundle install --deploy`, before copying over the code you've changed.  Personally I don't mind the cost of rebuilding when I add dependencies, since 99% of my changes still won't involve a rebuild.  That said, you might look into using golang's new Bundler inspired dependency manager: [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep).  With dep installed, I'm pretty sure you can just copy your `Gopkg.toml` and `Gopkg.lock` into your workdir, run `dep ensure`, and then copy your code.  This will only pull dependencies when the Gopkg has been updated - otherwise docker will be able to reuse the cached layer with your previous dependencies installed.  Sorry for the long edit!

Comment: That works, but ignores one part of my original question (so not sure it fits here): Your solution doesn't involve 'go get' at all. If dependencies change you still have to rebuild the container. Either that or you also put the golang binary output folder into a volume (for persistance) - but that would be against what I was trying to do, encapsulating the entirety of the test in the container.

Answer (score 1):

As govendor is outdated, new approach called **go modules** is recommended [migration path](https://go.dev/blog/migrating-to-go-modules).

With go modules adding cache layer is simple as adding following steps:

```
FROM golang:1.18-buster
WORKDIR /go/app/myapp

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build .
```

The copy mod and sum file will take care of invalidating cache od download command.
By the way the *CGO_ENABLED=0* allows build to run on Alpine Linux. Set it to 1 for dynamic glibc linking.

Answer (score 1):

With current Docker, one can use more tricks to cache and speed up go builds:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/go/pkg/mod \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
    go build app.go
```

With such cache no need to "go get / go mod download" before "go build".

Above will work for root user and default configuration. Use `go env GOCACHE` and `go env GOMODCACHE` to get values for your specific paths.

Docker documentation of this feature is here: https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#use-the-dedicated-run-cache - with the caveat that they don't mention one can use "--mount" more than once; but it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to comment on @Bogusław Kałka's answer, but due to my low reputation, I post another answer.

With Go v1.21.6, it appears that the default GOMODCACHE has been changed.

```bash
$ docker run --rm golang:1.21.6 go env | grep -e GOCACHE -e GOMODCACHE 
GOCACHE='/root/.cache/go-build'
GOMODCACHE='/go/pkg/mod'
```

So, the build command should be:

```bash
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
    go build app.go
```