# Create docker container to run `go test` with all module dependencies downloaded and cached

Tags: docker, go

I want to test my Go code in a CI environment which requires using Docker.  How do I create a Docker image that has all the dependencies listed in `go.mod` already downloaded and compiled so that `docker run $IMG go test` uses the cached artifacts?

#### The desired properties of this image:

- The image only uses `go.mod` to compile dependencies. I don't want to use the full source code because then any change to source code would invalidate the Docker layer that hold cached dependencies.
- `docker run $IMG go test ./...` doesn't redownload or recompile dependencies listed in `go.mod`.
- Avoid experimental Docker features.

#### Existing approaches

**Parsing go.mod and using go get**

From https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27719#issuecomment-578246826

This approach is close but it doesn't appear to use `GOCACHE` when I run `go test`.  This also appears to choke on certain module paths, like `gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1`:

```
FROM golang:1.13
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod ./
RUN set -eu \
  && go mod graph \
  | cut -d '@' -f 1 \
  | cut -d ' ' -f 2 \
  | sort -u \
  | sed -e 's#dd-trace-go.v1#&/ddtrace#' \
  | xargs go get -v
```

```
docker run --mount /src:/src $IMG go test ./...
```

**Using DOCKER_BUILDKIT with a mount cache**

Originally described in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27719#issuecomment-514747274. This only works for `go build`.  I can't use it for `go test` because the cache mount is unmounted after the RUN command so it doesn't exist in the created Docker image.

This also depends on experimental docker features.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM golang:1.13 as go-builder
ARG VERSION
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src/
# With a mount cache, Docker will cache the target directories for future
# invocations of this RUN layer. Meaning, once this command is run once, all
# successive calls will use the already downloaded and already compiled assets.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
    go build ./server
```

Comment: did you find a good solution?

Comment: Similar case here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72127803/4494515

Answer (score 1):

I often put `COPY go.mod` on the very begin of a Dockerfile, as it does not change that often.

```golang
FROM golang:1.14.3 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN go build -tags netgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o app .

FROM centos:7  
WORKDIR /root

COPY --from=builder /app/app .
```

So, if you go mod does not change, the line `RUN go mod download` only run for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

In your dockerfile if you run go get ./... it will download all the dependencies to your docker image based on the go.mod and go.sum. You can also add the --insecure flag to the go get command if you are dealing with internal self signed repositories. Very similar to go mod download. Aside from that you can have a shell script that actually initiates the Go test ./... and reports it out to your CI environment if that allows, I know that Gitlab allows this.

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --update git gcc musl-dev
RUN apk update && apk add bash
COPY . /app
RUN go version

WORKDIR /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
RUN git config --global http.sslVerify false
RUN go get ./...

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x ./unitTest.sh
RUN ./unitTest.sh

WORKDIR /app/cmd/svr
RUN go build -o app
RUN chmod 700 app

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /root/
ARG build_stamp
ARG git_commit
ARG build_number
ENV BUILD_STAMP=$build_stamp
ENV GIT_COMMIT=$git_commit
ENV BUILD_NUMBER=$build_number
COPY --from=builder /app/cmd/svr .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./app"]
```

and the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TESTS=$(go test -v -covermode=count -coverprofile=count.txt ./...)
echo "$TESTS"

if echo "$TESTS" | grep -q "FAIL" ; then
  echo ""
  echo "One or more Unit Tests for app have Failed. Build will now fail. Pipeline will also fail..."
  echo ""
  exit 1
else
  echo ""
  echo "All Unit Tests for application have passed!"
  echo "Running Code Coverage..."
  echo ""
  COVERAGE=$(go tool cover -func=./count.txt)
  echo "$COVERAGE"
  exit 0
fi
```