# AWS CDK Golang and Go modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cdk, cicd

I try to create a CICD pipeline for my Go project. I use Gitlab, AWS CDK Golang. In my **.gitlab-ci.yml**, I attach a Golang latest docker image and run **cdk deploy**
The problem is that (via my organization's policy), the CICD runner has no internet access, so I cannot download neither docker image nor Go dependencies (On a test environment everything works OK). The issue with my docker image I solved via uploading it to AWS ECR, and now the runner can get the image. But what about dependencies? I executed **go mod vendor** and downloaded all the dependencies. Then, I commited them to Git. When runner works, I see my vendor folder and all the files, but I CDK does not use it! It tries to go to the internet! I started my docker image locally and cdk deploy works in it...
In my **.gitlab-ci.yml** I set: **export GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor**.
In my CDK I use code like this:

```
lambdaFunction := awscdklambdagoalpha.NewGoFunction(stack, jsii.String("BackendLambda"), &awscdklambdagoalpha.GoFunctionProps{
    Runtime:      awslambda.Runtime_PROVIDED_AL2(),
    Entry:        jsii.String("./src"),
    Architecture: awslambda.Architecture_ARM_64(),
    Bundling: &awscdklambdagoalpha.BundlingOptions{
        GoBuildFlags: jsii.Strings(`-ldflags "-s -w" -mod=vendor`),
    },
    Environment:          &e,
    FunctionName:         jsii.String("BackendLambda"),
    Description:          jsii.String("backend Lambda function"),
    Role:                 applicationRole,
    Vpc:                  vpc,
    MemorySize:           jsii.Number(128),
    EphemeralStorageSize: awscdk.Size_Mebibytes(jsii.Number(512)),
})
```

But it still does not use my **vendor** folder
At least I decided to try to disable modules via GO111MODULE=off. If so, I receive an error at once:

```
$ cdk deploy
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
```

Here is my full output (you can see folder structure and environment):

```
    Getting source from Git repository
00:05
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/repo/backend-lambda/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out b3097c57 as detached HEAD (ref is test-deploy-docker)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:05
$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
$ ls -la
total 44
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Feb 13 21:22 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root            68 Feb 13 21:22 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root           128 Feb 13 21:22 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            62 Feb 13 21:22 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1403 Feb 13 21:22 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           417 Feb 13 21:22 README.md
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          2543 Feb 13 21:22 cdk.json
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1157 Feb 13 21:22 go.mod
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          7155 Feb 13 21:22 go.sum
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          7872 Feb 13 21:22 backend-lambda2.go
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           680 Feb 13 21:22 backend-lambda2_test.go
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            75 Feb 13 21:22 src
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root            80 Feb 13 21:22 vendor
$ pwd
/builds/repo/backend-lambda
$ export GO111MODULE=off
$ go env
GO111MODULE='off'
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/root/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/root/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS='-mod=vendor'
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/usr/local/go'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='local'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.21.7'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD=''
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build606705016=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'
$ cdk deploy
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
Subprocess exited with error 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

If GO111MODULE=on, the behaviour is:

```
$ cdk deploy
go: github.com/Masterminds/semver/v3@v3.2.1: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/%21masterminds/semver/v3/@v/v3.2.1.mod": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

So, I cannot understand: does CDK unable to work with **GO111MODULE=off**? If **GO111MODULE=on**, why does it still go to the internet? Any ideas how to build (no care with or without modules)?..

Comment: Very little still works with `GO111MODULE=off`, modules have been used for years now are are required for any dependency version >v1

Comment: I agree absolutely, but I cannot deploy both with or without modules if pipeline has no intertet access. Still cannot find out the reason.

Comment: Don’t try to create a vendor directory, use the builtin module cache to cache the dependencies.

Comment: Could you provide any details? Code example or some article about this?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200363/create-docker-container-to-run-go-test-with-all-module-dependencies-downloaded or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266332/manually-fetch-dependencies-from-go-mod (https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-2/)?

Comment: Also see this: https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-cache

Comment: Also you might find an enterprise-controlled Go module proxy useful–say, here at my $dayjob we have Artifactory deployed on premises which caches all the Go modules ever fetched via it during development. By extension, if the code run in CI/CD jobs is told to use that proxy (via a properly set and exported [`GOPROXY` env. var.](https://go.dev/ref/mod#resolve-pkg-mod)) it will hit your internal proxy and fetch from there.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer my own question now.
After diving deep into the code, I have finally found out that the issue with **go vendor**  is in AWS CDK code.

**File cdk.json.**

```
 {
  "app": "go mod download && go run backend-lambda2.go", // <-- see here!!
  "watch": {
    "include": [
      "**"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "README.md",
      "cdk*.json",
      "go.mod",
      "go.sum",
      "**/*test.go"
    ]
  },
```

That's why **cdk deploy** does not work offline. Remove **go mod download**, set **GO111MODULE=on** and build with **-mod=vendor** and you will succeed.